# Hibernate Lucene add an OR operator for an ENUM

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Hibernate Lucene add an OR operator for an ENUM

I implemented this code and is working well

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(MyClass.class).get();

Query query1 = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("title", "description").matching(keywords).createQuery();

Query query2 = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields(STATE.ENABLED).createQuery();

List<Query> listOfQuery = new ArrayList<Query>();

listOfQuery.add(query1);
listOfQuery.add(query2);

Query finalLuceneQuery=new BooleanQuery();
for (Query query : listOfQuery) {
    ((BooleanQuery) finalLuceneQuery).add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
}

FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(finalLuceneQuery, MyClass.class);
```

But now I want to add to the "second query" the possibility to ask STATE.DISABLE (like an OR clause)

I tried doing like this

```
Query query2 = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields(STATE.ENABLED + " " + STATE.DISABLE).createQuery();
```

but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can create a boolean query.

```
Query query2 = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields(STATE.ENABLED).createQuery();
Query query3 = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields(STATE.DISABLED).createQuery();

BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
bq.add(new BooleanClause(query2 , BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
bq.add(new BooleanClause(query3 , BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
```

then you can add bq in your list

```
listOfQuery.add(query1);
listOfQuery.add(bq);
```